# What's going on with MathJax today?

Tags: bug

I'm looking at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424778/the-meaning-of-a-parameterization-of-the-logarithmic-distribution).

It says:

> $$
> \Pr(X=x) = \frac{-p^x}{ x\log(1-p)} \text{ for } x = 1,2,3,\ldots\, \tag 2
> $$

Now I will set that in an inline, rather than displayed, context:

$\Pr(X=x) = \frac{-p^x}{ x\log(1-p)} \text{ for } x = 1,2,3,\ldots\, \tag 2$

It starts with P(X=x), and in the display above I don't see that at all, nor do I see the expression after the "equals" sign, and where it says "for x = 1,2,3..." I see the top half of the word "for", the top bar of the "equals" sign, and the top halves of the three digits.

Are others experiencing this? I've never seen this before. Is someone working on fixing this?

[image]

Comment: They look the same to me. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica : This has happened to me on several different machines today, with various different postings on both stats.stackexchange.com and math.stackexchange.com $\qquad$

Comment: Don't see anything wrong either. Operating system & browser detail might help.

Comment: It doesn't happen here neither. Could you make screenshots.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica : I've added a screenshot. Just below the words "This is a discrete probability distribution" you see a display matching the description I wrote, and that's obviously not what it should look like.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus : Done. $\qquad$

Comment: I can see it in your screenshot, but not on my screen, neither here nor on the linked thread. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Everything above looks fine to me, using the HTML-CSS renderer with FireFox $70.0$ on Windows $7$. This may be related to the Math SE meta questions [MathJax formulas hidden behind text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30842/mathjax-formulas-hidden-behind-text) and [Sometimes MathJax does not render some valid symbols: an example.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/sometimes-mathjax-does-not-render-some-valid-symbols-an-example), with it stating that it appears to occur with certain versions of Chrome.

Comment: @JohnOmielan : I'm viewing this on Google Chrome, not on Firefox. The same thing happened on my laptop and on several machines in labs on a university campus.

Comment: If I view this page using Chrome, I can still see both lines.

Comment: That is odd because when I view it from Chrome I get the same wrong display as the OP.

Comment: Here it is again: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412692/how-to-calculate-the-region-in-u-v-plane-in-transformation-of-variables#comment7018747_3412692